# koma-script: Problem with \footnote and \RaggedRight

Tags: footnotes, koma-script, ragged2e

Here's an MWE (using koma-script v3.25):

```
\documentclass[paper=a8]{scrartcl}

\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
%\addtokomafont{footnote}{\RaggedRight}

\begin{document}
foo\footnote{bar}
\end{document}
```

Here the result without `\RaggedRight`:

[image: without RaggedRight]

And here the same with `\RaggedRight`, un-commenting the corresponding line:

[image: with RaggedRight]

Question: What must I do to preserve the original horizontal position of the footnote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use `\addkomafont` or `\setkomafont` to change the alignment of the footnote text. You can redefine `\raggedfootnote`(available since KOMA-Script version 3.23).

Example:

```
\documentclass[paper=a8,DIV=9]{scrartcl}[2017/04/13]
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand\raggedfootnote{\RaggedRight}

\begin{document}
foo\footnote{bar bar bar bar bar bar bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't aware that \raggedfootnote has been introduced recently.

Comment: I've just tested it in my real-world document.  Everything's fine :-)